# how to handle Button Click Events in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a button with an id **btn_status** as

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="btn_status">Enable</button>
```

and like to show an alert when I press the button with this function:

```
$('#btn_status').click(function(event){
  alert("button is clicked");
});
```

What's the problem with this function? I can't see any message alert

I load my script.js on /var/www/html/form/index.php and the jquery code button are on /var/www/html/form/ajax/readRecords.php

The button is created with this code when the readRecords.php is executed:

```
...
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $status = $row['register_status'];
        if ($status == "Active") {
            $register_status = '<button class="btn btn-success" id="btn_status">Enable</button>';
        }
        else {
            $register_status = '<button class="btn btn-warning" id="btn_status">Disable</button>';
        }

        $data .= '<tr>
                        <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['first_name'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['last_name'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
                        <td width="1%">'.$register_status.'</td>

...
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code. Check the console for errors as you probably have a configuration problem somewhere, ie. you forgot to include jQuery.js in the page, you didn't put your code in a document.ready handler, or there's two `#btn-success` elements in the DOM

Comment: there aren't any errors on log. I load my script.js on /var/www/html/form/index.php  and the jquery button are on /var/www/html/form/ajax/readRecords.php

Comment: How does that work? All scripts need to be referenced from one page

Comment: have one index.php and load on some "div" the content of ajax/*php

Comment: is the button added dynamically? if so you have to delegate the click to it.

Comment: I update the post.

Comment: Please use the `edit` link under the question to add information. Also, if this button is added via AJAX then that is the issue, you need to use a delegated event handler.

Comment: Yes, its seems like your button is added dynamically, take a look at my answer below.

Comment: yes. When generate a table, the button is created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('body').on('click', '#btn_status', function(event){
  alert("button is clicked");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wwWaldi/3xy4woq7/19/

Comment: the button is added dynamically so if put this code can see anything...

Comment: What do you mean? this is the same code you have above with a few minor changes to make it work on a dynamically created element.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my code :) 
I hope It will help you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btn_status').click(function(event){
      alert("button is clicked");
    });
});
```

Comment: the button is added dynamically so if put this code can see anything...